# Creating new 'belongs-to' relation in Laravel with form requests

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6, laravel-formrequest

I am new to Laravel and can't quite wrap my head around the Form Requests and how to use them. In simple cases, it's simple enough but what I need is a conditional creation of a related model before progressing with the rest of the request. Let me explain.

```
//Job model
job_id PK
client_id
some_field

//Client model
client_id
external_id
name
```

Now in my Create Job interface, I have a `Select2` combo box that uses `AJAX` to search 2 different sources and can produce 3 different results.

So, say I am creating new Job and can have a POST looking like any of these:

*Script found a Client with id 21, we just want to save, it all is simple*

```
'client_id' => 21
'some_filed' => Whatever
```

OR

*Script didn't find a Client but we did a search of external API and returned this Identifier, which I can then parse to create a new Client. This needs to be done before I save Job as I need to have a client_id ready for it*

```
'client_id' => '196c3c7e34cde1d4593391ddf1901fd7'
'some_filed' => Whatever
```

OR

*Script finds neither local Client nor a remote datapoint so we want to create a new Client using just the name provided. Of course this has to happen before saving the Job*

```
'client_id' => 'My new client name'
'some_filed' => Whatever
```

Where do I perform all this functionality?

My first procedural guess would be to stick `$data['client_id'] = Client::HandleClientAndReturnId($data['client_id'])` in `StoreJob's` `validationData()` before returning the result.

But how would I handle/report possible validation issues with creating new Client and how to manage transaction - I don't want to create a Client if validation of Job fails.

I am using Form Requests and actually am parsing several models in the request already, but those are `HAS_ONE` type of relationships so I create them after the Job. Here I need to reverse the process. Here is what I have in my controller, if that is of any use:

```
class JobController extends Controller
{
  public function store(StoreJob $request, StoreJobDataAdd $request_2, StoreJobDataSup $request_3)
  {
      $job = Job::create($request->validated());

      if ($_POST['add_on']) {
          $job->dataAdd()->create($request_2->validated());
      }

      if ($_POST['sup_on']) {
          $job->dataSup()->create($request_3->validated());
      }

      return new JsonResponse([
          'success' => true,
          'message' => __('New Job has been created.')
      ]);
  }
}
```

Here are my relations:

```
class Job extends Model 
{
  public function dataAdd()
  {
      return $this->hasOne(JobDataAdd::class, 'job_id', 'job_id');
  }

  public function dataSup()
  {
      return $this->hasOne(JobDataSup::class, 'job_id', 'job_id');
  }  

  public function client()
  {
      return $this->belongsTo(Client::class, 'contact_id', 'contact_id_client');
  }
}
```

I have a feeling I am missing the right way to do it but not quite sure where to look for the answers so please point me in the right direction.

**Clarification:**

The objective of the whole exercise is to allow users to create new Clients or select existing by using one combobox. It's a Select2 box. For unfamiliar - a dropdown replacement that has an ability to free-type a string that is used to search for existing records and if not found it sends to the server what user typed in. Something like a dynamic dropdown with ability to search and add options by the user.

Comment: Wouldn't you create a new client at the point of not finding a client either local nor remote and then retrieve the new id from the new Client object.... I'm a bit confused with the line  `'client_id' => 'My new client name'`

Comment: You also wouldn't use `$_POST['name']` Your logic is a bit hard to understand. 
In Laravel use the injected request object `$request->input('name')`

Comment: @EdwinKrause No, I only want to create client if the Job is created. Don't want to have unused clients hanging around. The last scenario, you unsure about, happens when a user enters a name that returns no hits, no ids. Then Select2 returns a string that the user entered. I wast to use that string as the name of a new client. In fact, a name is the only required field for the Client to be created. Good advice on $_POST, I tried explaining the logic the best I can... sorry :).

Comment: The `StoreJob`, `StoreJobDataAdd` class are they extending Request class? The `->validated` method only returns the values which have validation rules applied. And how do you get 3 $requests into that store method? Very confusing.... https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#form-request-validation